# How can I specify optional parameters when copy files in Openstack Swift using Java API

Tags: java, rest, rackspace, openstack-swift, rackspace-cloudfiles

I'm using Rackspace Cloud Files (Openstack Swift) in Java application, and have the following scenario:
I upload files to a container (from web app, through my java rest backend) to a temporary location in rackspace container, and than, when some event happens (user confirms form saving), I need to move those files to a persistent location in that (the same) container.

I need those files to be downloaded then from my web app, so when uploading a file I specify header:

```
Content-Disposition=attachment;filename=thefilename.xxx
```

Also I specify header for files in my temporal storage *X-Delete-At*, so they could de automatically deleted if user doesn't save the form.

For copying file I use method from [ObjectApi](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/quickstart/?lang=java):

```
boolean copy(String destinationObject, String sourceContainer, String sourceObject)
```

It copies file content, file metadata, but **doesn't copy Content-Disposition**.
It seems that there is no way to set it after copying.

The problem is that [Cloud Files REST API](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/storage-api-reference/object-services-operations/#copy-object) allows to specify Content-Disposition header for copied target file, but Java API doesn't.
I wonder if there a way to extend that API or call that service with required header somehow alternatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me to solve the problem, is to upgrade `jcouds` libraries to [v. 2.0.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jclouds.provider/rackspace-cloudfiles-us/2.0.3).

In this version [ObjectApi](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-swift/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/swift/v1/features/ObjectApi.java) contains parameterized `copy()` methods allowing to specify another headers for a copied file (sending `X-Fresh-Metadata` header).

This is how I specify `Content-Disposition` header, and avoid copying `X-Delete-At` header:

```
Map<String, String> contentMetadata = new HashMap<>();
contentMetadata.put("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
contentMetadata.put("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myfilename.jpg\"");
objectApi.copy(toPath, containerName, fromPath, new HashMap<>(), contentMetadata, CopyOptions.NONE);
```